# Website not allowing scroll on IOS ( works on Desktop and Android )

Tags: css, ios, scroll, css-animations, svelte

I recently built a website in svelte and after deploying, I realized that I am unable to scroll down on IOS. I asked a fellow dev and he said it was working on android. I am not sure why this happens, but I think it has to do with the back that I am using a Keyframe on the body to hide the scroll bar until after a splash screen animation is finished ( because if I don't do this, the user can just scroll past the splash screen, which looks ugly).

Here is the code for the keyframe...

```
@keyframes bodyFade {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  to {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
}
```

```
body {
animation: bodyFade 6s forwards;
}
```

Comment: you tagged wrong tags, remove `android` and add `ios`

Comment: Changed Thank you!